# How to launch a new Wordpress blog without all articles showing up as new in RSS

Tags: php, rss, wordpress, rss-reader

We have an existing blog using Drupal and feed burner with a decent number of subscribers. We're going to launch a new blog that we've created using Wordpress and we're migrating all the old articles over.

How do we avoid all of our subscribers seeing "new" articles in the RSS feeds that they've already read before? I'm under the impression that the "new" article button is managed by the RSS reader itself and I'm unsure if there is a standard way for each app to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you cannot. The reader (the client) determines the read/unread status. There's no *flag* so to speak that you can set to tell the client it's old news.

Comment: My friend says you can keep the guid the same, just map old to new, assuming your reader hashes articles based on the guid.

Comment: Oh, well, you could do it that way though you'd have to do some extreme SQLing, right?